# How to create a random header location in PHP

Tags: php, random, http-headers

Is it possible to load 2 different header location in separate blank pages using php?

```
 <?php

 $state= $_GET['state'];
 $zip= $_GET['zip'];

 header ("Location:http://www.site1.com/test?CID=1&state=$state&zip=$zip");
 header ("Location:http://www.site2.com/test?CID=2&state=$state&zip=$zip");
 ?>
```

If not, how can I set this up so it randomly loads 1 of them?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have the page redirected to a random URL using [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/array_rand):

```
<?php
$arr = array("http://www.site1.com", "http://www.site2.com");
header ("Location: " . $arr[array_rand($arr)]);
```

Comment: I'm declaring a few variables at the beginning : $state= $_GET['state']; $zip= $_GET['zip']; Doesn't seem to work a the moment. Updating the example

Comment: @detonate:  Change the single quotes (`'`) to double quotes (`"`).

Comment: Thanks Tim, your suggestion worked flawlessly... Owe you a beer!